# Java MongoDB Aggregation example not working

Tags: java, mongodb, aggregation-framework

I am trying to implement Mongo Aggregation in Java and have tried more than 1 approach but still not able to make a simple use case work. 
Pom dependency:

```
    <parent>
      <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
      <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
      <version>1.3.1.RELEASE</version>
      <relativePath />
    </parent>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-mongodb</artifactId>
        <exclusions>
            <exclusion>
                <artifactId>spring-core</artifactId>
                <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            </exclusion>
            <exclusion>
                <artifactId>spring-expression</artifactId>
                <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            </exclusion>
            <exclusion>
                <artifactId>spring-context</artifactId>
                <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            </exclusion>
            <exclusion>
                <artifactId>spring-beans</artifactId>
                <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            </exclusion>
        </exclusions>
    </dependency>
```

Below are the 2 approach i have tried,
First one:

```
    MongoDatabase database = mongoClient.getDatabase("xxx");
    MongoCollection collection = database.getCollection("XXX");
    collection.aggregate(
        Arrays.asList(
            Aggregates.match(Filters.eq("name", "Test"))
        )
    ).forEach(printBlock);
```

Second one:

```
    DB db = mongoClient.getDB("xxx");
    DBCollection collection = db.getCollection("XXX");      
    DBObject match = new BasicDBObject("$match", new BasicDBObject("name", "Test")); 
    AggregationOutput output = collection.aggregate(match);
    for (DBObject result : output.results()) {
         System.out.println(result);             
    }
```

I am able to get the database and collection details but the aggregation does not work. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Here is a sample document which this aggregate query should return:                                                                      { 
   "_id" : ObjectId("57fXXXXXXX"), 
   "name" : "Solar Farms", 
   "global" : true, 
   "icon" : "no icon"
  }

Comment: Isn't match should be `"name" : "Solar Farms"` ?

Comment: Yes I am using "name" : "Solar Farm" in my code, there is a typo error what i sent you.

Comment: okay then the code you have is fine. It is something else. Make sure again the collection and db name are correct and you have authorization set up correctly if you are using one. Please add the actual code the way you see it.

Comment: I have debugged and check that database credentials are correct. I am not getting any error but dont get any output. I think I should update the version of java-mongo driver.

Comment: Nope I don't think so. Your code runs fine here at my end with the set up you provided.You still have a typo Solar Farm vs Solar Farms